# How to integrate Froala Editor File upload with Rails 4.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4.2, froala

In my Rails 4.2 application, I would like to upload about 20-50 documents (`pdf/docx/rtf/txt`) using Froala Editor and save the uploaded documents in the path `/public/media/documents`. I want to post the upload to `/admin/media/documents#upload`. Ideally I also want to choose from documents that have already been uploaded when I click on the file-upload button in the editor.

On the form where this happens, I have some javascript that starts like this:

```
javascript:   $('#page_content').editable({
    imageUploadURL: '/admin/media/documents/',  /not sure about this
    inlineMode: false,
    theme: 'royal',
    // Set custom buttons with separator between them.
    buttons: ['html', 'sep', 'undo', 'redo', ...
```

Can someone please help me with the missing pieces in the puzzle?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add

```
javascript:   $('#page_content').editable({
    imageUploadURL: '/admin/media/documents/',
    imageUploadMethod: 'POST'
}
```

take carrierwave as an example: [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), you probably need to read it thoroughly

Add the gem into your Gem file

```
gem 'carrierwave'
```

and then

```
bundle install
```

Create a uploader model throught carrierwave

```
rails g uploader Image
```

It is something look like this:

```
-- app/model/uploader/image_uploader.rb
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    storage :file

    def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
end
```

It will generate image_uploader.rb in app/model/uploaders

In your document model:

```
class document < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :picture, ImageUploader
end
```

So now you need to create a route for your uploading, from your path it might look like =>

```
-- config/route.rb

resource :admin do
    resource :media do
      post 'documents' => 'documents#upload'
    end
end
```

In your document, you need to implement upload action, to save time and clear answer. I will skip csrf token cerify.

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token 

    ...
    # you need you adjust your code.
    def upload
        @document = admin.media.documents.new 
        @document.picture = params[:file]
        @document.save

        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render :json => { status: 'OK', link: @document.picture.url}}
        end
    end
    ...
end
```

Hope this explains the question clearly.